# Access to a resource based on permissions using JWT in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an API using .NET Core 2.0. I already have JWT working with roles but I want to move to use it with permissions. I have a defined list of permissions and the idea is to create dynamic roles based on that permissions.

Because roles are dynamic I can't use role-based authentication, so I need to authenticate a user based on permissions.

Suppose you have a static list of permissions. For example:

- Create post
- Edit post
- View all posts
- View my posts

Now let's say I have roles:

```
public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RolePermission> Permissions { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a dynamic role and select a list of permissions from given static example list.

Now I want to create a Role called "Administrator" with this permissions:

- Create post
- Edit post
- View all posts

My idea is to have a JWT like this:

JWT Example:

```
{
  "iat": 1416929061,
  "jti": "802057ff9b5b4eb7fbb8856b6eb2cc5b",
  "role": "Administrator",
  "permissions": {
    "posts": {
      "actions": ["readall", "create", "edit"]
    }
  }
}
```

Now I just want to check for permissions in order to access a resource in the API.

The only solution is to create policies for every permission? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi Martin. First of all, that blog is extremely dated, and should be considered a poor reference for usage against an API with scope level authorization. Auth0 now does this out of the box.  Note also, you should be applying the scopes to JWT Access Token (NOT the Id token) . Still not sure I fully understood what you are trying to achieve?  You'd like to provide a set of scopes on the JWT access token received for a given user authentication, and base what scopes are issued on some static permissions table for that user?

Comment: Hi arcseldon! Thanks for your reply. My idea is to have some static permissions. You can create dynamic roles with selected permissions (from static list). For example some permissions: view all posts, view only my posts, add posts, delete posts, etc, etc. I just want a user to give access or not to a resource based on permissions.

Comment: So assigning the scopes dyamically at authentication time is easy enough - just still unclear what we are keying the scopes off.  I think where you are referring to "permissions" you actually mean "scopes".   Still unclear what you mean about dynamic Roles - are you suggesting the user's Roles frequently change?

Comment: Will post an answer as soon I understand how to ascertain what Roles a user has. Is this attached to the user profile app_metadata in Auth0, is it available as an HTTPS lookup etc?

Comment: Yes, scopes are permissions. The idea about roles is to select a couple of permissions from a static list and give a name. For example, I have a list of permissions (add all kind of posts / add posts about technology). Now Dynamically I create a role called Administrator and I select a the permission "add all kind of posts". Then I create another role with custom permissions from static list. I know I can create this as claims in JWT but how can I create this in an array in JWT called permissions, and then check for a specific permission in the resource auth?

Comment: Updating question...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current question, I believe what you require is to setup an API in the Auth0 Dashboard - see [docs here](https://auth0.com/docs/apis). You can then define default scopes to the API as you wish.

In order to influence the scopes that actually get applied for a given user authentication according to the Role to which they belong, you could define a Rule in Auth0 Dashboard. Here is a really simple example:

```
function (user, context, callback) {

  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};

   if (user.app_metadata.role === "Administrator") {
     context.accessToken.scope = 'openid read:posts create:posts edit:posts';
   } else if (user.app_metadata.role === "User") {
      // define likewise as needed..
   }

   callback(null, user, context);
}
```

Whether the `role` statically applied to the user profile, or dynamically looked up etc, is less clear and will depend on your requirements. But if you set this up, you should receive an JWT access token with a payload containing something like the following (for the situation where the user authenticating had `Administrator` role.

[image]

You can then secure your .NET Core API to verify the access token accordingly. If you are not using an API, then theoretically you "could" use the ID Token instead... (as the application itself is the consumer). But I have based the above on the understanding you wish to authorize a request against some API...?

Comment: Arcseldon, thanks for your answer but I'm not using any external API. I'm using my own logic.

Comment: Well, very old school approach - used to be something like this - https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-mvc-sso-sample/tree/master/app1-portal#add-role-based-authorization-by-creating-an-auth0-rule   here, the rule would update the user profile. Then you can use code authorization grant flow and /userInfo endpoint to pull down the permissions.

Comment: I'm not using Auth0. I'm just using JWT in my own implementation.

Comment: Hi Martin - thanks for clarifications :D  - this "might" interest - https://auth0.com/blog/when-to-build-and-when-to-buy/
  Best of luck with your project.